# Why does ProxyFactoryBean throw "No qualifying bean of type" with @Autowired? And doesn't throw with pre-getBean()?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, proxy, spring-aop

I've tried to use `ProxyFactoryBean` with `@Autowired`, but it throws an exception at the `setInstrument` method.

The question - why does it work with previously called `getBean` method or `@DependsOn`? I'm trying to understand what Spring performs for these additional steps.

Thank you in advance!

I have two interfaces - `Singer` and `Instrument`. And two implementations for them - `GuitarSinger.class` and `Guitar.class`.

```java
public interface Singer {
    void singSong();
    Instrument getInstrument();
}
```

```java
@Service
@Lazy
public class GuitarSinger implements Singer {
    private Instrument guitar;

    @Autowired
    public void setInstrument(Instrument instrument) {
        this.guitar = instrument;
    }

    @Override
    public Instrument getInstrument() {
        return guitar;
    }

    @Override
    public void singSong() {
        System.out.println("I'm singing a song");
        guitar.play();
    }
}
```

```java
public interface Instrument {
    void play();
}
```

```java
public class Guitar implements Instrument {
    @Override
    public void play() {
        System.out.println("I'm a guitar!");
    }
}
```

This interface is meant for for proxy introduction:

```java
public interface GuitarChecker {
    boolean isGuitarOk();
}
```

This mix-in class implements the interface we want to introduce to the proxy:

```java
public class GuitarCheckerMixin extends DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor implements GuitarChecker {
    @Override
    public boolean isGuitarOk() {
        System.out.println("I don't know how to check the guitar");
        return true;
    }
}
```

And eventually, the configuration class with `main` method:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.annotation.test")
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public ProxyFactoryBean checkedGuitar() {
        ProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryBean = new ProxyFactoryBean();
        Instrument guitar = new Guitar();
        proxyFactoryBean.setTarget(guitar);
        proxyFactoryBean.addAdvisor(new DefaultIntroductionAdvisor(new GuitarCheckerMixin()));
        proxyFactoryBean.setProxyTargetClass(true);
        return proxyFactoryBean;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appContext
                = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        Singer singer = appContext.getBean(Singer.class);
        singer.singSong();
        Instrument instrument = singer.getInstrument();
        GuitarChecker guitarChecker = (GuitarChecker) instrument;
        guitarChecker.isGuitarOk();
    }
}
```

If I run `main`, I will get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.annotation.test.Instrument' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:759)
    ... 17 more
```

But if I add one of these two steps (works ok with only one of them), it will work correctly and print result.

1. Add `@DependsOn("checkedGuitar")` to `GuitarSinger`:

   ```java
    @Service
    @Lazy
    @DependsOn("checkedGuitar")
    public class GuitarSinger implements Singer {
   ```
2. Add one more line `appContext.getBean("checkedGuitar")` to `main`.

   ```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appContext
            = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        appContext.getBean("checkedGuitar");
        Singer singer = appContext.getBean(Singer.class);
        singer.singSong();
        Instrument instrument = singer.getInstrument();
        GuitarChecker guitarChecker = (GuitarChecker) instrument;
        guitarChecker.isGuitarOk();
    }
   ```

With one of these two updates, the application will print the following lines:

```
I'm singing a song
I'm a guitar!
I don't know how to check the guitar
```

Could you please help me with understanding of the issue? Why does it work with `@DependsOn` or `getBean()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Spring user, so I do not know how proxy bean factories and the other stuff you use are meant to be used canonically. But how about his?

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q70623926;

import org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultIntroductionAdvisor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("de.scrum_master.spring.q70623926")
public class Config {
  @Bean
  public ProxyFactoryBean checkedGuitar() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    ProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryBean = new ProxyFactoryBean();
    proxyFactoryBean.setTarget(new Guitar());
    proxyFactoryBean.setProxyTargetClass(true);
    // Make CGLIB proxy implement the same interfaces as the target class
    proxyFactoryBean.setProxyInterfaces(Guitar.class.getInterfaces());
    proxyFactoryBean.addAdvisor(new DefaultIntroductionAdvisor(new GuitarCheckerMixin()));
    return proxyFactoryBean;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class)) {
      Singer singer = appContext.getBean(GuitarSinger.class);
      singer.singSong();
      ((GuitarChecker) singer.getInstrument()).isGuitarOk();
    }
  }
}
```

This yields:

```
12:39:49.887 ...ProxyFactoryBean - Advice has changed; re-caching singleton instance
12:39:49.887 ...ProxyFactoryBean - Advice has changed; re-caching singleton instance
12:39:49.887 ...ProxyFactoryBean - Advice has changed; re-caching singleton instance
12:39:49.887 ...ProxyFactoryBean - Advice has changed; re-caching singleton instance
12:39:49.887 ...ProxyFactoryBean - Advice has changed; re-caching singleton instance
12:39:49.979 ...DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'guitarSinger'
I'm singing a song
I'm a guitar!
I don't know how to check the guitar
12:39:50.023 ...AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Closing ...AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@61baa894, ...
```

Comment: thank you for your answer!
Yes, your solution is correct, but still it doesn't explain why Spring works with DependsOn and getBean() steps.
Also, the idea of ProxyFactoryBean is to not add additional code for casting object (as you provide at instrument() method).
So, it works, but I'd like to use benefits of ProxyFactoryBean :)

Comment: Thanks for challenging my first solution. I improved it, see above. The key is to use `ProxyFactoryBean::setProxyInterfaces`, then it works without `@DependsOn` and without an extra bean definition fetching the object from the proxy bean.

Comment: Hi!
yes, I've tried the same and it works. We can add your solution to the list of DependsOn and getBean(). 
The problem is - I don't understand what Spring performs for DependsOn and getBeam(). I know how to make this code works - we already have several solutions :)
But I'm trying to understand mechanism of Spring framework. How does getBean() changes already existing singleton bean...

Comment: Does Spring add Interfaces to Proxy object after calling getBean()?

Comment: Yes, if it creates a proxy automatically, because for example the bean is targeted by an aspect, advisor or interceptor. You need to do the same if you want to create a proxy manually instead of simply using Spring AOP.

Comment: You could simply use [AOP introductions via `@DeclareParents`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-introductions) instead of re-inventing the wheel. I can help you with that, if the manual is not helpful enough.

Comment: it's not reinventing the wheel. It's one of the approaches for Spring AOP, like AspectJ annotation or aop namespace. But I got your point, maybe I'm trying to dig too deep. And it's better to focus more on functionality instead.
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: The best way to thank me would be to accept and upvote my answer. I believe that I presented a solution which does not involve any of the extra steps you needed before. It just works the way you wanted it to. My solution is superior to your first two approaches in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying it can't find any Bean that implements an interface `Instrument`. The only class that you have implementing `Instrument` is class `Guitar`. Annotate it with `@Component` so Spring can find it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer!
If I annotate Guitar with @Component, Spring will inject bean with exactly Guitar type to Singer. But I need proxy bean from ProxyBeanFactory.

Comment: then you need to define a @Bean in `Config` class with return type of Instrument and return ProxyBean instead.

Comment: @J Asgarov, yes, it will work, but it's a "hack".
I'd like to use benefits of ProxyFactoryBean as they were designed. Of course, we can redesign code with returning proxy.getInstacne(). And it will work even with ProxyFactory (not ProxyFactoryBean)
Also, it doesn't explain why it works with '@DependsOn()' and 'getBean()'.